# Wait for two change listeners to change both

Tags: java, changelistener

I have a short question regarding `PropertyChangeListener`s.

I have a `Person` class which has 3 attributes. Two of them are the `x` and `y` coordinates which the person has on a map.

I want to update the map whenever the coordinates of a person change.
So my problem is to detect when not only `x` or `y` change, but both do.

That's how far I got. I hope you can help me.

Person.java:

```
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeSupport;

public class Person {
    private int x, y, hp;
    private PropertyChangeSupport changes = new PropertyChangeSupport( this );

    public Person (int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public void setX( int x) {
        int oldX = x;
        this.x = x;
        changes.firePropertyChange( "x", oldX, x );
    }

    public void setY( int y) {
        int oldY = y;
        this.y = y;
        changes.firePropertyChange( "y", oldY, y );
    }

    public int getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public int getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void addPropertyChangeListener( PropertyChangeListener l ) {
        changes.addPropertyChangeListener( l );
    }

    public void removePropertyChangeListener( PropertyChangeListener l ) {
        changes.removePropertyChangeListener( l );
    }
}
```

Map.java:

```
private void initPeople() {
    people = new Person[amount];
    PropertyChangeSupport
    for (Person p : people) {
        person.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent e) {
                // IF Person x AND y changed DO something
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, either, you need to know the location of each `Person` (as a seperate state) and check those values against the values which have been changed OR you need to perform the check within the `Person` and generate a seperate "location changed" property changed event only when both properties are changed

Answer (score 0):

You can store the boolean xChanged and yChanged properties in person's property change listener class, and then in callback:

```
xChanged | ="x". equals(e.source);
yChanged |="y". equals(e.source);
if(xChanged & & yChanged ) {
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can instead of have two fields for **People** coordinate (`x` and `y`) merge them to other object (you can call it `Coordinate`). That allow you to work with coordinate of **People** like entire thing. And of course you have fire changing of it in one call.